# I need to print it in a single line

Tags: perl, unix

I'm writing a script in `perl wfor` which I'm using unix commands.I need to print the output of this commands in a single line in perl.

```
$table_name=`cat diff_out|cut -d "|" -f1`;
$col_name=`cat diff_out|cut -d "|" -f2`;
$index_name=`cat diff_out|cut -d "|" -f3`;
print "$table_name |$col_name |$index_name |DROPPED|$col_name|$index_name";
```

I'm getting output one below the other. I want it in one line.

Comment: Please show an example of the input data and the desired output and the current output.  You probably only need 3-5 lines of data.  You can always create a string (replace your `print` with `my $output =`), then map all the newlines into spaces (`$string =~ tr/\n/ /;`), and finally print that (`print "$string\n";`).  I'm suspicious, though, that it isn't what you actually want.

Comment: INPUT :1,2d0
< OLAPTABLEVELTUPLES|ID|OLAPTABLEVELSSEL|
< AW$AWCREATE10G|GEN#|AWCREATE10G_I$|
OUTPUT:

Comment: OUTPUT:1st column |2nd |3rd|dropped|2nd |3rd

Comment: can you post your content of `diff_out` ?

Comment: Using the shell (and a [useless `cat`](http://iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) to boot) to split a line from within Perl is just insane.

Comment: Please edit example data into the question where you can format it so that it is legible, rather than trying to place it in a comment where it is illegible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `chomp` operator for every variable to skip the new line character in that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $table_name=`cat diff_out|cut -d "|" -f1`;
chomp($table_name);
my $col_name=`cat diff_out|cut -d "|" -f2`;
chomp($col_name);
my $index_name=`cat diff_out|cut -d "|" -f3`; 
chomp($index_name);                               
print "$table_name |$col_name |$index_name |DROPPED|$col_name|$index_name\n";
```

Output:

```
OLAPTABLEVELTUPLES |ID |OLAPTABLEVELSSEL |DROPPED|ID|OLAPTABLEVELSSEL
```